# ¿Cómo obtener dato de tabla en relacion many-to-many laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pivot

Tengo una aplicación con el sistema Auth de Laravel el cual consiste en tres tablas:

- users
- roles
- role_user (tabla pivot)

Lo que quiero lograr es que en el listar users (index), cada user pueda mostrar el campo description de la tabla roles.

He buscado por todos lados y no he dado con un ejemplo que pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que la relación esté hecha correctamente según la documentación de Laravel, en la misma documentación se muestra un ejemplo casi igual a lo que buscas:

Modelo User

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The roles that belong to the user.
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}
```

Controlador y vista:

```
$users = App\User::all();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
        {{ $role->description }}
    }
}
```

Como siempre, todo lo encuentras en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Muchas gracias, esa anidacion de foreach me estaba faltando, siempre encontraba ejemplos con solo el foreach `($user->roles as $role)` , pero eso no me permitia recuperar los datos de users